# reasons to have a multi-species crew for a zoo

Tags: internal-consistency, society

Orbiting around a planet is a very large space mall. It exists as a refuge away from planetary law where aliens from across the local group could gather together and sell to others of different alien races without worrying about the laws of their native planet(Kinda like a black market).

This opportunity isn't just reserved for the buying and selling of objects, and that is where the zoo comes in. Aw planetary law always keeps the interesting creatures out of the reach of the public, because of dumb reasons such as, they're endangered, can't handle captivity, or need the tourism to fuel their planets economy. So here, if you can get them in, the creatures can stay no matter how illegal.

And my question is basically what's a good reason for the owner of one of these zoos get a multi-species crew  instead of just them all or most of his species, and instead have a diverse cast of alien races working for his zoo?

Comment: OK, this question is almost destined to be closed.  Let's see if we can avoid that.  (a) What does the zoo have to do with whether or not a crew (apparently for one of the zoos?) is multi-species or not?  (b) What does the lawless black-market mall have to do with whether or not a crew is multi-species?  Does the reason why a multi-species crew or a single-species crew play an important part of your story?  This could easily be one of those questions where there is no single best answer and you should simply make a choice and move forward with your story.

Comment: it is called a zoo for a reason... I'm just saying ;D

Comment: Please [edit] to make clear what your references to *they* and *them* are.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer would be to have all of these species have *vastly* different physical traits and abilities. Maybe a big strong alien race that can handle the bigger and more dangerous creatures, a water-breathing one to better maintain the aquatic exhibits, a tiny one to get into tight spaces, etc.

Use your imagination. With all the crazy kinds of aliens people have come up with and the insanely diverse needs a zoo full of exotic alien creatures would have, there's got to be plenty of jobs with vastly different physical requirements and demands.

Comment: while its a good point, it is still easier to have all the creatures in a working in a zoo be the same species so they can communicate better. Plus technology can take care of a lot of those problems as well.

Comment: Is that the world you've already decided on? Is technology advanced enough to make biological differences meaningless when it comes to doing a job, but there isn't very good translation technology?

Comment: @user45751 what do you mean by the "local group"?  James Blish used "local group" to mean a volume of space with a radius of 25 or 50 light years centered on Earth.  Astronomers use "local group" to mean a small group of galaxies including ours.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Group

Answer (score 3):

The biggest reason for maintaining a crew of diverse species on the zoo staff is as a reward to the entity making the donation. If the specimens are not able to be kept in a zoo within their local system (planet, galaxy, etc.) the entity making the "donation" of that specimen probably is now an outlaw at "home" and needs a job and some sanctuary. By providing both the zoo owner enhances their reputation for *fair-dealing*, and encourages donations that might otherwise never happen.

Of course, the fact that the donors are now "wanted" for criminal acts at home just provides another point for sub-plots in your work. Providing a job is easy, sanctuary maybe not so much.

Not a complete reason, for a totally diverse crew, but one that could be used for a small sampling of the zoo creatures is creature needs, etc. For some creatures it might be possible that for them to thrive (as opposed to merely survive) they might require contact, physical or emotional, with their native planet's inhabitants. It could be as simple as a domesticated cat needing some physical contact with their human on a daily, or frequent, basis. Or, it could be as complex as a mental symbiosis that the creature cannot survive without, though it may not be significant to the "human" in the equation. In either case, it gives other plot points to play with.

Answer (score 3):

The best reason is the crew also double as exhibits (more or less). Why just settle for alien creatures when you can also see alien races too.

It's not really acceptable to lock intelligent beings up for the amusement of the public but when you pay them as staff and tour guides, you get a twofer.

Comment: I like the concept. That could even avoid "humanitarian" complaints about mistreatment of "sentient beings" if there was _employment_ available for possibly sentient specimens. As in, there are some who think our dolphins are sentient. Of course there are those who question the sentience of _Homo sapiens_ as well.

Answer (score 1):

> what's a good reason for the owner of one of these zoos get a multi-species crew instead of just them all or most of his species, and instead have a diverse cast of alien races working for his zoo?

The main reason I can think of is simply that different crew will have different specialties in relation to to different creatures, possibly native to their own worlds.

So someone from Planet X is more likely to have expert knowledge of creatures from planet X than someone from planet Y.

You hire people with the best expertise you have and in this case that means means people are most likely to be from different planets.

Let's also remember a zoo, legal or illegal, needs veterinary experts, not just people to shovel manure.  And you're more likely to find e.g. a human who likes horse, dogs or (yuch) cats than a human that likes (Star Trek moment :-)) Targs.  And likewise the animals would be more accustomed to their native species than alien ones.

So it makes a lot of sense to crew with aliens if you've an zoo with many alien species.

> law always keeps the interesting creatures out of the reach of the public, because of dumb reasons such as, they're endangered, can't handle captivity

For the record, those aren't dumb reasons. :-)